# Ionic 3 Angularfire2 order by on last objects node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

In my ionic app I want to fetch those orders which has `pending` status. My firebase data structure is like below.

```
orders:
    user001:    // this is user 1
        11168128:
            name: "order 1"
            status: "pending"
        11168129:
            name: "order 2"
            status: "canceled"
    user002:    // this is user 2
        11168130:
            name: "order 3"
            status: "pending"
    user003:    // this is user 3
        11168131:
            name: "order 4"
            status: "pending"
        11168132:
            name: "order 5"
            status: "canceled"
```

Now I want to get `pending` status records. I am doing this but it is giving me wrong result

```
this.orders = this.db.list(`orders`, ref => ref.orderByChild('status').equalTo('pending'))
  .snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
       return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
});
```

I don't want to change my structure of my database. Then how can I get my desired result?

Answer (score 0):

I have this code friend orderby to name, and you change the value orderbychild

```
    getAll() {
    return this.db.list(this.PATH, ref => ref.orderByChild('name'))
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
      })
  }
```